# Jquery animation happening on multiple divs

Tags: jquery

So I have a structure something like this

```
<div class="content-block">
    <div class='hidden'> Hidden Content </div>
    <div class='click'> Click Me </div>

    <div class='hidden'> Hidden Content </div>        
    <div class='click'> Click Me </div>

</div>
```

I want Jquery to animate the hidden content directly so that it expands the height and width. My jquery is

```
$(".click").click(function(){ 
    $(".click").prev(".hidden").animate({
        width:100%, 
        height: 500px
    }, 500);
});
```

The problem I am having is that this animates all the .hidden divs not just the one directly previous to .click

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specify the context, with `$(this)`:

```
$(".click").click(function(){
    $(this).prev(".hidden").animate({width:100%, height: 500px}, 500);
});
```

In your original code you were selecting *all* `.click` elements and, therefore, all their preceding `.hidden` siblings.

Comment: I knew I was missing something easy. Guess I need more coffee : )

Comment: No worries at all; if everyone was always at the top of their game then I guess I'd have no rep..! =D